# Replacing multiple for loops with list iterators

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, listiterator

I want to replace multiple nested forloops with nested listiterators instead, but wanted to know if this would be a problem with calling .next(). So if I say, for example, Iterator attackIter = currentAttackers.iterator();, and instantiate an iterator for each of three lists, then run through first a nested forloop for lists A and B, and then one for B and C, will that be an issue for the second loop since I already called .next() all the way up to the end of list B? The original loops look kind of like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < listB.size(); j++) {
            collide(listA.get(i), listB.get(j));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < listB.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < listC.size(); j++) {
            collide(listB.get(i), listC.get(j));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since your code iterates the `listB` twice you will need to create two iterators for `listB`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not required to use `Iterator`s explicitly, the best way to use `List` `Iterator`s is like this (replacing `AType` and `BType` with the appropriate types):

```java
for (AType a : listA) {
    for (BType b : listB) {
        collide(a, b);
    }
}

for (BType b : listB) {
    for (CType c : listC) {
        collide(b, c);
    }
}
```

This uses `Iterator`s behind the scenes and makes things simple. See Oracle's article, ["The For-Each Loop"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), for some reasons why it's beneficial to do it this way instead of using `Iterator`s explicitly.

---

If you need to use `Iterator`s explicitly, you can do it like this (based on the examples in ["The For-Each Loop"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)):

```java
for (Iterator<AType> i = listA.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    AType a = i.next();
    for (Iterator<BType> j = listB.iterator(); j.hasNext(); )
        collide(a, j.next());
    }
}

for (Iterator<BType> i = listB.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    BType b = i.next();
    for (Iterator<CType> j = listC.iterator(); j.hasNext(); )
        collide(b, j.next());
    }
}
```

As pointed out by others, you have to use a new `Iterator` each time you loop through a `List`, because an `Iterator` can't be reset for another iteration through a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator can only be used once. There are no methods for resetting it. Each time you want to iterate through `listB` you will need to create a new iterator.

You are really much better off using a for-each loop or even the forEach method:

```
listA.forEach(a -> listB.forEach(b -> collide(a, b)));
```